# How to fit a model into an optimization function

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I have the following linear model:

$F(x,w)=w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^D w_ix_i + e_i $

Have the following square loss minimization function:

$L_D(w)={1/2} \sum_{n=1}^N( f(x,w)-y)^2 $

I need to fit the linear model into the  optimization function and solve it.

So I am assuming I need to solve something like this where I replaces the $ f(x,w) $ with $w_0+\sum_{i=1}^D w_ix_i + e_i$:

$L_D(w)={1/2} \sum_{n=1}^N( w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^D (w_ix_i + e_i )-y)^2 $

I have no idea how to approach this equation. Can someone suggest how to simplify it.

Comment: To minimize $L_D(w)$, set the gradient equal to $0$ and solve for $w$. It's easier if you use matrix notation and compute the gradient using the chain rule. The computation is done frequently on this site; maybe Google for how to derive the "normal equations" for least squares problems.

Comment: Try gradient descent. You can learn this from Calculus.

Comment: Are you planning to use any specific software package? The solution process will depend on the package you choose. On MATLAB, you could use "lsqnonlin" function to solve this problem.

Comment: We don't need to use gradient descent or an iterative optimization algorithm such as Matlab's `lsqnonlin` to solve a linear least squares problem, though. We can just solve the normal equations.

Comment: Thank you  littleO, can you please more details